# Wordpress wptouch mobile site redirection

Tags: wordpress, redirect, mobile

I have installed wptouch for my wordpress site (example.com) and now I have another subdomain as m.example.com which is pointing to example.com. If I type in m.example.com in any mobile then example.com mobile version should be viewed. Please let me know how can I manage this redirection using the common database and common files.

Thanks in advance.